# trigger MQTT broker to publish will message with Paho Java client

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I'm using Paho Java client currently, is it possible to trigger the broker to send the will message in code? since using disconnect() will not result in a will message being sent by the broker

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill client pid form terminal. This should trigger LWT after standard MQTT timeouts.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's not how the LWT works.

The broker will only publish the LWT if the client times out (or the socket drops) without the client sending a disconnect message.

There is nothing to stop you manually publishing the same message before calling `disconnect()`

Comment: thanks, but I'm going to build a tool to test whether a broker is in line with protocol standards, am I doing it the right way?

Comment: What I've described is the spec. The only time a broker will publish the LWT is if a client fails to disconnect cleanly

Comment: If you want to test LWT, kill the client and wait for the keep alive to time out